# can a phone detect 3D posture of a person with the camera?

Tags: camera, performance

Does an Android phone have everything it needs to reconstruct someone's posture, by using the camera sensors?
If yes, are nowadays' phones fast enough for this?

Here's a [video of what I mean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmXbS5DkSsw) on the XBox Kinnect

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK, no. [Kinect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect?oldformat=true) has depth sensor that allows to measure distance between camera and objects, while normal camera on Android doesn't have that.

Comment: @AndrewT. wasn't there one Android device introducing something similar, using a second camera lens? I remember having read about this, but don't remember which device or manufacturer that was. Ah, here: [Dell to put depth-sensing 3D cameras in more Android](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2844192/dell-to-put-depthsensing-3d-cameras-in-more-android-windows-devices.html), plus [HTC announces the new One with depth-sensing camera](http://www.engadget.com/2014/03/25/htc-announces-the-new-one/)

Comment: @Izzy I also heard about that news, but as currently written, I assume the questions asks for all recent phones, which is not correct.

Comment: Definitely true, @AndrewT. Different interpretation of the question's "*an* Android phone" versus its "nowadays' *phones*": I focussed on the former, you on the latter #D